# How to limit all html elements max-width and height of all sites on firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

Element with very high height or width value causes crash on firefox.
Ex:

```
<div style="height: 99999999999999px;"><div>
```

How to prevent this?

Comment: Why would you ever need an element that tall?

Comment: Don't visit those sites?

Answer (score 0):

I think a big part of the problem is that Firefox (at least previous versions) tends to use a lot of memory all by itself even when nothing major is happening.

Loading a huge amount of data would mean it requires even more memory and CPU resources than it normally does, and it normally demands quite a lot from the system. So if the amount of data was enormous, it could use the whole resources and Firefox is polite enough to give up rather than crash the computer.

I would guess the performance would vary if you try this on a very low-end system versus a high-end system with lots of memory and fast CPU.

Of course it also depends what you mean by crash. The precise meaning of crash is that it stops working and quits, whereas you could be talking about it just hanging (it stops working but does not quit) in which case it is possible that it is still working but struggling to render the page before you lose patience.

If you manually close Firefox before the page is rendered, it does not technically count as a crash, simply a hang or that the user has not been patient enough to wait for the page to load (of course there is a limit to anyone's patience!).